# Why would I want to disable my observatory?

Tags: kittens-game

As far as I can tell, all of the effects are positive. Why is there an option for turning the observatories off?

```
Observatory (1)
---------------
Increases the chance of the astronomical events by 0.5%, +25% to the science
output, +1K to the max science. Turning off observatories will only disable
event bonus.

scaffold 0.06 / 55.00
slab 38.50
iron 825.00
science 1100

Effects:
--------
Science bonus (%): 0.25
starEventChance: 20
starAutoSuccessChance: 1
Max Science: 1000

Yearning to one day catch the red light fairy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason to do it is if you get sick of seeing the constant astronomical events in the log.

Eventually you'll be able to get an upgrade which hides and automatically activates them, so once you reach that point, you would never do it.